# Mobile Push message is not being Received

Tags: marketing-cloud, mobilepush, mobilepush-android

We have recently implemented Mobile Push SDK for our Android App and we were able to see that the attributes are getting injected successfully on Contact Builder.

However, on performing a Mobile Push Send, the status within MobilePush Send shows that the Send is delivered but in reality we have not got any notification on our app.

We are still in the development phase and we are using BrowserStack to review the results.

Need your expertise to figure out why the sends are not being received on our Android App

Comment: What does the SDK's output to the LogCat say?  Do you have an open support ticket?  There's not enough information in this question to help.

Comment: Turn on Logging, review it, if it's not obvious then post your logs here.  Ref. https://salesforce-marketingcloud.github.io/MarketingCloudSDK-Android/trouble-shooting/loginterface.html

Comment: Have you tried any of the steps listed in the Troubleshooting Push section of the documentation?  Ref. https://salesforce-marketingcloud.github.io/MarketingCloudSDK-Android/trouble-shooting/trouble-shooting-push-setup.html

Comment: @BillMote We tried to run the script on an online terminal, but we are getting the error "bash: !\: event not found"

Comment: We are running the script:

 #!/usr/bin/env bash
export PUSH_TOKEN=#Use push token from SDK's PushMessageManager#getPushToken() method
export FCM_SERVER_KEY=#Use value from Firebase console
curl --header "Authorization: key=$FCM_SERVER_KEY" \
  --header Content-Type:"application/json" \
  https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send \
  -d "{\"to\":\"$PUSH_TOKEN\",\"data\":{\"_m\":\"test_message\",\"alert\":\"It Worked!\",\"title\":\"Test Push\", \"_sid\":\"SFMC\"}}"

Comment: Omit `#!/usr/bin/env bash`.  Additionally, https://www.codecademy.com/learn/bash-scripting/modules/bash-scripting would be a good overview of bash scripting.

Comment: @BillMote I tried running the script without #!/usr/bin/env bash, but I am getting the same error.  We tried to test this Push Notification via FCM and the notification was received successfully.

Comment: What do the logs say?  Do you have an open support case?

Comment: Also, I simplified that command for you to copy & paste, but you will still need to put in your own values for the push token and server key: `export PUSH_TOKEN=yourpushtokengoeshere && export FCM_SERVER_KEY=yourfcmserverkeygoeshere && curl --header 'Authorization: key=$FCM_SERVER_KEY' --header Content-Type:'application/json' https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send -d '{\"to\":\"$PUSH_TOKEN\",\"data\":{\"_m\":\"test_message\",\"alert\":\"It Worked!\",\"title\":\"Test Push\", \"_sid\":\"SFMC\"}}'`

Comment: @BillMote I have created a Support Case and I am awaiting their response.